# Play Framework 2.6.x ebean : DataSource is null in production only

Tags: ebean, playframework-2.6

**Java Version**: 9.0.4 (I tried on 10.0.2 as well)

**Play Version**: 2.6.15 (also 2.6.18)

**Play-ebean**: 4.1.3

The project runs fine with sbt run, but trying to run it in production (exactly the same environment), results in this error. "DataSource user is null?"

Any insight is appreciated!

Here's the full log, my conf setup is below.

```
[warn] o.h.v.m.ParameterMessageInterpolator - HV000184: ParameterMessageInterpolator has been chosen, EL interpolation will not be supported
[error] io.ebean.Ebean - Error trying to create the default EbeanServer
java.lang.RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?
        at org.avaje.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:207)
        at org.avaje.datasource.core.Factory.createPool(Factory.java:15)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.getDataSourceFromConfig(DefaultContainer.java:334)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.setDataSource(DefaultContainer.java:278)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:117)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:88)
        at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:45)
        at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:58)
        at io.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.getWithCreate(Ebean.java:202)
        at io.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.<init>(Ebean.java:160)
Oops, cannot start the server.
Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2218)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4147)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4151)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:5140)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:5146)
        at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements.forMember(StackTraceElements.java:70)
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatSource(Errors.java:817)
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatSource(Errors.java:796)
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatInjectionPoint(Errors.java:849)
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatSource(Errors.java:811)
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatSource(Errors.java:796)
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.format(Errors.java:590)
        at com.google.inject.CreationException.getMessage(CreationException.java:50)
        at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:396)
        at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:485)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2788)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:897)
        at java.base/java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream.println(Throwable.java:752)
        at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:659)
        at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:648)
        at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:639)
        at play.core.server.RealServerProcess.$anonfun$exit$1(ServerProcess.scala:49)
        at play.core.server.RealServerProcess.$anonfun$exit$1$adapted(ServerProcess.scala:49)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at play.core.server.RealServerProcess.exit(ServerProcess.scala:49)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:74)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:25)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.inject.internal.util.LineNumbers.<init>(LineNumbers.java:66)
        at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements$1.load(StackTraceElements.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements$1.load(StackTraceElements.java:43)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3708)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2416)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2299)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2212)
        ... 27 more
```

application conf setup:

```
db {
  default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  default.url="jdbc:mysql://1.1.1.1/db_name?characterEncoding=UTF8&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
  default.username=user
  default.password="pwd"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to have worked for me. The problem is erratic in nature, so I cannot be sure though.

```
@Inject
    public Repository(EbeanConfig ebeanConfig, DynamicEvolutions dynamicEvolutions,
                      DatabaseExecutionContext executionContext, Config config) {
        this.ebeanServer = Ebean.getServer(ebeanConfig.defaultServer());
        this.executionContext = executionContext;
    }
```

So this is basically injecting both EbeanConfig and DynamicEvolutions into any class that is calling `Ebean.getServer();`

I found this on this issue thread,

https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean/issues/51

used this on 2.6.x with ebean 4.1.3, and as mentioned, it seems to have worked.